# How to display formatted HTML data in kendo ui grid column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added columns in the kendo ui grid dynamically.

I have a column named 'Formatted' with the data displayed in the below format.

```
<div class="class1"> <div>This is <strong>bold </strong>text.</div> <div> </div> <div>This is <em>italics</em> text.</div> <div> </div> <div>This is a <a href="http://google.com/">hyperlink</a>.</div> <div> </div> <div>Bulleted list:</div> <ul> <li>Bullet #1</li> <li>Bullet #2</li> <li>Bullet #3</li></ul></div>
```

I want the 'Formatted' column to display the data as below.

```
This is bold text.
 
This is italics text.
 
This is a hyperlink.
 
Bulleted list:

 Bullet #1

 Bullet #2

 Bullet #3
```

How can I do this.

Please anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a [column template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template).

Example:

```html
<script id="ob-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="class1"> 
        <div>This is <strong>bold </strong>text.</div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is <em>italics</em> text.</div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>This is a <a href="http://google.com/">hyperlink</a>.</div>
        <div> </div>
        <div>Bulleted list:</div>
        <ul>
            <li>Bullet #1</li>
            <li>Bullet #2</li>
            <li>Bullet #3</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</script>
```

and then, when you define the columns use it:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: ...,
  columns: [ 
    { field: "...", title: "...", template: $("#ob-template").html()}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks OnaBai again for your help. I understood that I need to write template attribute to that particular field, while adding column. What I actually need to write in the 'ob-template' script tag. Because the column value could be the one I mentioned in example or the value could be just a div with p tag with value in it or the value could be just a div tag with value. So in that case what I actually need to write in the script 'ob-template'. Please suggest on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Also the most outer div's class value is different for each record. Also I am using the javascript file with jquery in that, how can I write the script 'ob-template' syntax.

Comment: What you write in the template does depend on what you want it to look like. The template is _pure_ HTML with the advantage that you can add the value of the field.

Comment: Check this (http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) on writing templates

Comment: Really thanks for your help and suggestion. Can I please get any example to see from where I can get any idea. Because I just have to write code in javascript file and cal that file from the application. So if I try to create the template type id="ob-template" as described earlier, how can I do that in the javascript file. Really thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to instantiate a template from JavaScript or do you want to invoke a JavaScript function from inside a template?

Answer (score 0):

You can use template property: template: "#=rawHtmlDataVariable#" like this

```
<div id="grid"></div>
  <script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [ {
        field: "name",
        template: "#=rawHtmlDataVariable#"
      }],
      dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" } ]
});
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you render the Grid using Ajax

Here is the solution:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).ClientTemplate("#=convertToPlaintext(data.Name)#").HeaderTemplate("Name");
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
.Pageable( pageable => pageable
    .Input(true)
    .Numeric(false)
 )
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(430))
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("YouAction", "YourController").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
    .ServerOperation(true)
 ))
```

---

Then create a function javascript to convert html content to plaint text like this:

```
function convertToPlaintext(htmlContent) {

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = htmlContent;
    return div.textContent;
}
```

---

Thanks