# Passing a List<string> to a Kendo Grid in ASP MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've got a Kendo Grid in which one of the columns is passed a `List<string>`. Right now it displays `[object Object]`, but I'd like it to display the list of strings separated by commas. I found this answer: [Kendo Grid: How display List<string> in one cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782613/kendo-grid-how-display-liststring-in-one-cell)

But the solutions proposed don't work for me. It just prevents the grid from rendering at all.

This displays `[object Object]` in the column:

```
                     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.MyConfigModel>
                         ()
                         .Name("MyListGrid")
                         .Columns(columns =>
                         {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.myList).Title("My List").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal;text-align:center" }).Width(150);
                         })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(100)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("MyListGrid_Read", Model.ControllerName))
                        .ServerOperation(false).Model(model => model.Id(p => p.MyID)))
```

This causes nothing to be displayed:

```
                     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.MyConfigModel>
                         ()
                         .Name("MyListGrid")
                         .Columns(columns =>
                         {
                            columns.Bound(p => p.myList).Title("My List").ClientTemplate("# =iterate(myList) #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal;text-align:center" }).Width(150);
                         })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .PageSize(100)
                        .Read(read => read.Action("MyListGrid_Read", Model.ControllerName))
                        .ServerOperation(false).Model(model => model.Id(p => p.MyID)))
```

Here's my iterate function:

```
function iterate(object) {
    if (object !== null && object.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < object.length; x++) {
            html += object[x];
            html += ", ";
        }
        html = html.slice(0, -2);
        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pre-process (create comma separate string) before it binding it to the grid? Also, can you check if there are any errors in console?

Comment: @SangramNandkhile No errors in console. I thought about pre-processing, the only thing is, when displayed in the grid, a comma separated string is good, but when editing it's used to populate a Multiselect which wants an array. So I'd have to have two properties and copy/convert back and forth. It's doable, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

Grid:

```
columns.Template(p => { }).Title("My List").ClientTemplate("#= iterate(data) #").HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: visible; white-space: normal;text-align:center" }).Width(150);
```

Javascript:

```
function iterate(data) {
    if (data.myList!== null && data.myList.length > 0) {
        for (var x = 0; x < data.myList.length; x++) {
            html += data.myList[x];
            html += ", ";
        }
        html = html.slice(0, -2);
        return html;
    }
    return "";
}
```